# Convert code from EJS to Handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ejs

This maybe looks obvious but I can't figure out how to convert this working code from EJS to Handlebars.

`<%= configHelper.exportClient(__config, __config.path.base + 'api/db/schemas/')%>`

To render simple values it's easy `{{__config.path.base}}` but when I try to do some calculation or ternaire `if` condition it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using Handlebars, because while EJS allow to perform calculation, set variables and so on in a template file, Handlebars doesn't.

The only way to do it would be to write a handlebars helper, or to load the template with the pre-calculated variables and use them as it.